# |, > and < in numpy datatype

Tags: python, numpy

This could be a very silly question but I tried to google keywords like `less and greater signs in data type of numpy` and found no reference.

In the [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html) of `numpy`,

```
x = np.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], dtype=[('x', float), ('y', int)])
```

outputs

```
array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i4')])
```

But on my PC, the output is

```
array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)],
      dtype=[('x', '>f8'), ('y', '>i4')])
```

What do `<` and `>` in the `dtype` mean and why there is the difference?

Comment: My guess would be that its something like "little/big endian int/float #bits"... probably system-dependant.

Comment: I agree, this is a bothersome oversight in the documentation. I looked [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#structured-arrays) and [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html) and there is no mention of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The keywords `<` and `>` stand for [byte ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), aka *endianness*. It is the order in which bytes from numbers are stored (when numbers are compossed of more than 1 byte, e.g. int16, int32, float32...). [This page from the reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.byteorder.html) gives you all the information you need about it in numpy, but as a summary:

- `|` : it doesn't have a byte order because is redundant (on single byte numbers or strings)
- `<` : little-endian
- `>` : big-endian

As @tobias_k and @RobertKern pointed out, the *default* endianess, if not specified, is system dependant.

Comment: The default is indeed system-dependant, essentially determined by the CPU, not version-dependant.