# What is the meaning of vertical bar in array dtype ('|S58')

Tags: python, numpy

I have an error when I tried to do

```
np.savetxt(f, te_filename)
```

It returns an error of

```
% (str(X.dtype), format))
```

TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('|S58') and format specifier ('%.18e')

I checked the doc page,

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Seems that S stands for string and 58 is the length, what is the meaning of vertical bar then?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188619/and-in-numpy-datatype/38188707#38188707

Comment: `.18e` is a float formatting, the default for `savetxt`. Your `te_filename` is a string. It works with a '%s' format. But why use `savetxt` to write a string to a csv file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a [byte order specifier](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.byteorder.html), specifying "byte orders don't apply".

- '=': native
- '<': little-endian
- '>': big-endian
- '|': not applicable

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you mind further explain why in this case is not applicable? Isn't everything either big or little endian?

Comment: @LanceRuoZhang: There's no difference between a big-endian or little-endian 1-byte char.

Comment: `S` is a bytestring (regular string in py2), one byte per character.  `endian` applies to numbers.

Comment: A unicode string has a dtype like: `array('one',  dtype='<U3')`

Comment: glorious explanation