# Making an address object into a string

Tags: python, string, object, decode, encode

I have a giant dataset with addresses and I am having trouble converting address line 1 from object to string.

```
import pandas as pd
    
data = ['1111 S. Washington Street', '2222 S. Jefferson Ave', '3333 W. Madison Court #2']
      
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Address_Line1'])
df['Address_Line1_2'] = df['Address_Line1'].str.upper()
df['Address_Line1_2'] = df['Address_Line1_2'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', str(x)))
df['Address_Line1_2']  = df['Address_Line1_2'].astype('|S120')
print(df.info())
df.head()
```

There are special characters somewhere in the dataset, so I try to keep only alpha-numeric and then make it a string, but I end up with my dataframe above looking like this:

```
Address_Line1   Address_Line1_2
0   1111 S. Washington Street   b'1111 S WASHINGTON STREET' 
1   2222 S. Jefferson Ave   b'2222 S JEFFERSON AVE'
2   3333 W. Madison Court #2    b'3333 W MADISON COURT 2'
```

I see this is a "bytes" issue, but when I try to decode

```
df['Address_Line1_2'] = df['Address_Line1_2'].decode('UTF-8')
```

I receive "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'decode'".

How do I finish this text cleaning?

Comment: You are explicitly requesting conversion to bytestrings with the line including `.astype('|S120')`.  I think you can just get rid of that line.

Comment: That was easy enough, thanks. Just changed it to 'string' and everything is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with "bytes" that are encoding strings, you could interpret the data as columns of strings:

```
df['Address_Line1_2']  = df['Address_Line1_2'].astype('|S120')
```

Where [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) argument [means](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_data_types.asp):

`|` - [byte-order specifier](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.byteorder.html) (endianness not applicable - see: [|, > and < in numpy datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188619/and-in-numpy-datatype/38188707#38188707))

`S` - type string

`120` - length in bytes